# wp7 binding pushpin List to Maplayer

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, dictionary, bing-maps

I want to bind my pushpins (which is a list ) to the My Map`s Maplayer.

There is no such thing "ItemSource" in MapLayers attributes. How can I bind my Pushpin List Data to MapLayer?

```
<my:Map HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="map1" CredentialsProvider="KEY" >
    <my:Map.Children>
         <my:MapLayer x:Name="pushPinMapLayer" ??Binding what???}">
         </my:MapLayer>
    </my:Map.Children>
</my:Map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the link below as it is from a question I asked a while back (which part of it should solve your question)

[Binding Pushpins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684339/binding-pushpins-in-observablecollection-to-bing-maps-control-wp7)

I think the part that will help you the most is the Xaml (in the Map>ItemsControl element)

```
    <my:Map Height="520" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="468" ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed" ZoomLevel="1" CredentialsProvider="{Binding bingMapsCredentials}" >
        <my:MapLayer x:Name="myPushpinLayer"> 
             <my:MapItemsControl Name="Pushpinsss" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinCollection}" >
                 </my:MapItemsControl> 
        </my:MapLayer>
    </my:Map>
```

You need to add the MapItemsControl section under your MapLayer

Comment: I will try it tomorrow it most probably work My computer is not with me right now.

Comment: Thank it works first of all. But I have another question Why dont we use PushPin insteadof PushPinModel? Because I also want to use PushPins Content Property.

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure i understand. We are binding to a collection of pushpins, Windows phone will auto-magically go through the list and put all of the pushpins on the map for you

Comment: I solved the problem thanks. Yes it does actually I thought we cant add Content on it but when we bind it named with our Property name it worked. Thanks